# Checkbox with listview label

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a list view with some items. I want to add a check box in the right corner of list view "Label", which shows in the black color at the top of list view. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example it helps u too add check box on list view activity..

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-checkall-and-uncheckall-for-a-listview-in-android/